# Using licenses to restore purchase after reinstallation

Tags: c#, xml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store

My app needs a button to 'restore previous purchases'
Here's my code which is triggered when button is pressed

```
   #if DEBUG
                   var receipt = await CurrentAppSimulator.GetAppReceiptAsync();
    #else
                   var receipt = await CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync();
    #endif
                    var xmlRcpt = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlRcpt.LoadXml(receipt);
                    XmlNodeList xmlProductIdNodes = xmlRcpt.SelectNodes("/Receipt/ProductReceipt/@ProductId");


                    if (xmlProductIdNodes.Count == 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var md = new MessageDialog("Unable to verify purchase");
                            await md.ShowAsync();
                        }
                        catch { }
                        return;
                    }

                    foreach (var node in xmlProductIdNodes)
                    {
                        if (node.InnerText == "Product1")
                        {
                           //Enable feature 1
                        } 
                        else if (node.InnerText == "Product2")
                        {
                           //Enable feature 2
                        }

                    }
```

The problem is after publishing the app, "unable to verify purchase" is being hit. So is there something wrong with the xml parsing (this is my first time with xml) Or something else?
App targets windows phone 8.1 xaml

**UPDATE 1:** Somehow I feel, the problem is with the understanding of how store updates licenses. I tried a different approach since my only aim is to check whether a product is purchased or not. I submitted a beta app with this code using a button:

```
                var receipt = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses;

                if (receipt["Product1"].IsActive)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var md = new MessageDialog("Product 1 enabled", "Success!");
                        await md.ShowAsync();
                    }
                    catch { }
                    return;
                }
               else
                {
                  try
                  {
                    var md = new MessageDialog("Could not verify purchase");
                    await md.ShowAsync();
                   }
                catch { }
               }
```

Now the problem is, first time "could not verify" is hit. Then, I make the free purchase of Product1. Product1 verifies successfully. This is as expected. Now if I uninstall the app and reinstall, again the same behaviour i.e. the could not verify purchase.

How can I make sure that the licenseinformation gets the most recent information even after reinstall? Or anyway to trigger a refresh?

Will LoadListingInformationAsync() refresh the license?

Comment: I think that Loading listing information won't help here much - it only loads store's information, not options purchased by the user. When you run *GetAppReceiptAsync* - do you have connection with the internet? What kind of IAPS you use - Consumale/Durable? Have you tried to check *GetUnfulfilledConsumablesAsync*?

Comment: I am using durable product so no need of getting unfulfilled consumables.
Internet connection is working. Like I said, this problem only occurs after reinstallation. If purchase is made, in a particular installation, the function works fine. Is there any period in which I have to wait for the license to update after installing the app?

Comment: I even tried to directly put the result of GetProductReceiptAsync("Product1") to a MessageDialog. Again it works when the product is purchased in the same installation. After reinstallation, it probably generates an exception as no MessageDialog appears